# simple program to get and display name and dob of friend what is the error

Tags: arrays, c, string, structure

The program tells to take input name and dob from friend and display it using structures.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    struct friend {
        char name[40];
        int dd, mm, y;

    } f;
    printf("enter details");
    scanf("%c %d %d %d", &f.name, &f.dd, &f.mm, &f.y);
    printf("name is %c and dob is %d/%d/%d", f.name, f.dd, f.mm, f.y);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter details dasd 10 10 2004
name is £ and dob is 0/35/11408852
```

the output is giving this garbage value why?

Comment: What is the correct format specifier for a string? Is it `%c`, or is it `%s`?

Answer (score 2):

You should correct these issues:

- to read a word, you should use `%s` in `scanf` or more precisely `%39s` to read a word of up to 39 characters and a null terminator. `%c` reads a single character.
- to check that input was complete, compare the return value of `scanf` to 4, the expected number of successful conversions. As coded, `scanf()` will fail to convert the DoB if the name has more than 1 letter, hence the members `dd`, `mm` and `y` remain uninitialized, a potential explanation for the garbage output.
- to print the string in the `name` array, use `%s` in `printf`. `%c` expects an `int` and you pass an array or `char`, which is passed as a pointer to its first element. This has undefined behavior, another explanation for garbage output.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct friend {
        char name[40];
        int dd, mm, yy;
    } f;
    printf("enter details: ");
    if (scanf("%39s %d %d %d", f.name, &f.dd, &f.mm, &f.yy) == 4) {
        printf("name is %s and dob is %d/%d/%d\n", f.name, f.dd, f.mm, f.yy);
    } else {
        printf("invalid or missing input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```